# Magento 2 Mobile view menu links redirect to undefined page

Tags: magento2, category, megamenu, mobile-menu

I have an instance **Magento 2.3.3** In that I have installed the **Weltpixel mega menu** module and configure it.

**In sub-menu I have added custom HTML with ul > li tags**. The sub-menus are working perfectly in **desktop view** but **not working on the mobile view**.

I have categories as below and HTML as below:

- First Menu

  - Mens
  - Women's
  - Bags
  - Chairs
- Custom menu

  - Wine
  - Mouse
  - Ortho

When we click on **"First Menu"** or **"Custom menu"** on the mobile view it goes to an undefined URL. In the desktop view, it is working perfectly.

How to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!